# Could I use an RF modulator to broadcast signals from a Raspberry Pi to an analog tv over the air without the use of a coaxial cable?

Tags: rf, hdmi, tv

"Long" story, but I connected a digital-to-analog converter (for OTA TV) to my mom's 1984 Samsung CRT, and now I'm wondering, could I broadcast (on low power, of course) HDMI outputs to a TV OTA?

My original idea was to do the following:
HDMI to AV, AV to RF, connect RF output via coaxial cable to Samsung CRT.

Now I'm wondering if I could skip the coaxial cable altogether and use an antenna from the RF converter, then use an antenna on a different TV to connect the two OTA over a coaxial cable. Would this be possible or not?

Comment: Raspberry pi has analog video out (on the 3.5mm) so no need to convert from HDMI.   raspiconfig will help with choosing the right video standard.

Comment: I used to do exactly this with an rf modulator from an old vcr (I think) and an ntsc security camera. Don’t recall the range, sorry.

Comment: @Jasen Ok, how would I get the video from the 3.5mm jack? Just a normal aux cable?

Comment: @Bryan Do you remember if you had to use a signal booster or not?

Comment: @WilliamHunter no booster, just a piece of wire jammed into the modulator as an antenna.

Comment: it's 3 way aux cable with 3 RCAs, https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/oo46ih/i_mapped_a_few_trrs_cables_to_the_rca_connectors/

Comment: @Bryan Haha, that’s innovative. I tried with a paperclip and that didn’t go all that well. (Scanned only on “Air” frequencies over Cable frequencies, could be the reason it didn’t work)

Comment: @Jasen I didn’t even know that was a thing, thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to amplifiy the RF signal some,  but in theory it should work.  there's probably laws where you are about what frequencies and power levels you can use.

Comment: I thought I'd have to use an amplifier, but I don't know how much dB gain would be appropriate for this. Trial and error would work best.

Answer (score 1):

Not easily, and not with decent quality. Analog TV used amplitude modulation for the video, with a raster scan, and frequency modulation for the sound channel. You would need some way to convert the video to an old-fashioned NTSC signal on an AM carrier. You might have a chance to do sound only by creating an FM transmitter, but the TV might not recognize presence of the signal without the video carrier.

The easiest way to do what you want is to find an old video game RF modulator, which will accept video and audio via phono jacks, and connect its RF output to your receiver TV. "Broadcast" and "OTA" really implies transmitting over the air; if you're trying to actually transmit over the air, range and quality will be lousy, and it's not even legal.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. OP obviously has a box to convert HDMI to composite video and an RF modulator to convert it to antenna signal which can be fed into TV. The video would not be converted in software to NTSC signal.

Comment: I don't have any of those things, but I'm planning on purchasing the equipment you mentioned. The RF modulator I'm planning on buying is extremely simple, AV to RF out and ANT in. Question is if I could transmit that RF out throughout the house, and how would I do it?

Comment: @WilliamHunter Add a link to the RF modulator datasheet. It's doubtful it has enough power to transmit more than a few feet. An RF power amplifier would increase the range but it's illegal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I were to have a series of coax cables running through my wall, could I connect the RF out to the coax cables, or would that also be illegal?

Comment: Yes, you can use coax cables, completely legally. Connect coaxial cable splitters to get the number of outputs you need.

Comment: Alright, thanks. We already have a huge network of coax running through the ceilings and walls, so I'll see if I could to that to comply with FCC laws.

Answer (score 1):

Extremely bad idea. You'll blow out your neighbor's TV reception and get an FCC truck snooping around.

The analog TV channels *are still being used*.  They are simply being used for digital now.

What's more, they virtualized channel numbers, so the public identification/marketing channel no longer corresponds to their band in the spectrum. That allows FCC to maneuver channels to consolidate and free up spectrum. That is why digital TVs scan.  They check every channel and find, e.g. on channel 29, a station claiming to be ABC channel 7.  OK, when you enter channel 7 into your remote, it knows to look in spectrum channel 29.

Channels 2, 3 and 4, favorites of RF modulators, are all in active use by digital TV.  And it's not easy to know which channel, and it might change.  Also, cheap RF modulators are not good at avoiding overspill, so you could jam a lot of spectrum.

Comment: I could use a UHF channel that isn't often used, and I don't have neighbors close enough to distort their signal. I could probably use a lower-powered signal booster in order to not cause any TV reception interruptions.

Comment: @WilliamHunter TV stations aren't, as a rule, intermittent. Make sure you understood the thing about virtualization of channels.  Channel 7 may be broadcasting on UHF 29. Really.  It's different in every market.